# In Arkham Asylum, are there Riddler informers?

Tags: batman-arkham-city, batman-arkham-asylum

In *Batman: Arkham City* there are "green" criminals that you can interrogate for the Riddler's stuff.

Are these same green criminals available for interrogating in *Batman: Arkham Asylum*?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Arkham Asylum there are "Secrets maps" instead of the Riddler informants that are in Arkham city. The maps serve the same purpose, but are slightly more difficult to find as they don`t stick out as much as the green henchmen do.

Here is an example of one of the secrets maps:

[image: Riddler map]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a screenshot of this map? So I can understand how they are

Comment: Good suggestion. Check the answer again as I added an image of the map.